# How to access local variables of a module being tested in nosetests

Tags: python, python-2.7, nosetests

I am trying to write tests for a python module. One of the functions uses a while loop and does some local computation on a local variable (say Y) when condition X is satisfied.

Now I want to test whether this computation on Y is happening properly or not.

My initial approach was to use setup() & teardown() for each test method. In setup(), I tried to impose that  condition on X (say X = 0) and in the test_Y_method(),  I check if value of Y was updated propoerly.

But this gives me a NameError. So my question is how do I access local variables of a function in a Module and set their values in Nosetests ?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I did try to google it but couldn't find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: I don't exactly understand the situation. You have a module with an inner function and you're calling that function from inside a test? And you want to debug your function and see what happens? It sounds like you're looking for a debugger, not a unit test module.

Comment: Unit tests should test units, not their internal implementation details.

Comment: I think you are too much white-box-testing this. Either the computation for Y is relevant by itself - then make it another function you just use from our other one, and test in explicitly. Or Y is an implementation detail - then treat it as such, and don't bother about it.

Comment: If is hard to test, maybe a good idea should be review your design.